# create a listview with c++ QT

Tags: c++, qt, listview

I'd like to know how to create a simple ListView control with QT? I mean a table-like control that has multiple rows and columns, rows can be changed at runtime(edit/add/insert/remove row). I've been googling for a while, all the tutorials are about the three standard table-like controls: QListView, QTableView, QTreeView, but they seem to have limits

```
QListView: only one column
QTableView: row/column count is fixed
QTreeView: there is a expander in the first column
```

I prefer to use MVC in my application for performance, so I'm using the Qxxx**View**, I'm new to QT, any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: The number of rows and columns isn't fixed in QTableView. I don't see how it would pose limitations on your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the past you could use `addColumn()` method:

```
  m_treeView = new QListView();

  m_treeView->addColumn( "Tree" );
  m_treeView->addColumn( "First" );
  m_treeView->addColumn( "Second" );
  m_treeView->addColumn( "Third" );

  m_treeView->setRootIsDecorated( true );
  QListViewItem *root = new QListViewItem( m_treeView, "root" );
  QListViewItem *a = new QListViewItem( root, "A" );  
  new QListViewItem( a, "foo", "1", "2", "3" );
  new QListViewItem( a, "bar", "i", "ii", "iii" );
```

http://www.digitalfanatics.org/projects/qt_tutorial/chapter13.html

however since `Qt 4` it is not supported. Now list views are designed to view simple lists. You can use `QTableView` instead.